# php encode_json with foreign langues

Tags: php

json_encode decodes utf8:

```
$arr = Array(
        'name' => 'ბინტი',
        'count' => '15');
 $result = utf8_encode(json_encode($arr));
 echo $result;
```

result is

```
{"name":"\u10d1\u10d8\u10dc\u10e2\u10d8","count":"15"}
```

can anybody help?
p.s
sorry for Foreign language i couldnt post question with proper title

Comment: That's the expected result. If you decode it, it will become the proper characters again.

Comment: @OttoVacheishvili _foreign languages_ and as Pekka said, it's normal ;)

Comment: can u just post the code cause with decode-ing result is the same

Comment: and how do you decode it?

Comment: echo `json_decode($result)` will work if your file is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @OttoVacheishvili for the sake of [clarity](http://codepad.org/oVF8cMLF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested, your characters, using this javascript code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var a = "\u10d1\u10d8\u10dc\u10e2\u10d8"
     alert(a);
   </script>
```

Firefox printed this message:

[image]

As you see, your georgian characters are ok. So, `json_encode` is working correctly. BTW:

```
$result = json_encode($arr);
```

produces the same result as

```
$result = utf8_encode(json_encode($arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fully expected. Foreign languages with exotic characters don't fit into basic ASCII, so JSON is using some encoding sequence (`\u` + 4 hexadecimals (unicode sequence)) for representing your characters. When decoding the unicode sequence is converted back into real unicode characters.

This has the advantage that you won't have encoding issues when storing and reading JSON.

Comment: is that the only way to solve this problem?

Comment: @OttoVacheishvili Where's your problem exactly? What do you want to see? Raw unicode characters in JSON? Doesn't exist.